# Angular return value from function in subscribe to the outer function

Tags: angular

I need to return value from inside subscribe to outer function.
How do i do it?

return `this.innerf(text)` should be the return value of the outer function.
But I am unsuccesful in it
any ideas?

```
  public outFunc(text: any) {
   if (ss) {
  return this.innerf(text)
  } else {
  return this.getKeys().subscribe(x => {
    this.setKeys(x)
    return this.innerf(text)
  })
  }


 }
```

Comment: Hello. If you want people to read your questions, please show interest in your question yourself. The formatting you have currently says you don't care and you're less likely to get answers.

Comment: if you are using observables use the [rxjs/operators](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library). I imagine you ask about switchMap, unafortunatly the docs about rxjs it's very confussed but one time you know what operator use, google is plenty of good resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, since getKeys is asynchronous you will not be able to return its value as it resolves after it has been used.

You could either transform it to a promise, but then you'd still return a promise and not the value directly.

Either go full observable, or handle your initialization beforehand.

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried your approach using full observable but still not working

Comment: Then show us what you tried so we can help...

Comment: I took you suggestion to init it elsewhere . thanks